# Notification Emails in Mura not working

Tags: mura

I'm getting the following error message when I attempt to send a "Notify For Review" email in Mura.

> Message The current mail s erver settings for the site 'default' are
>   not valid.

This is a feature that worked for us before, but for reason has suddenly stopped working.  Under Email settings we have "Use Default SMTP Server" selected.  Mail Server/IP Host Name is and has always been blank.  Does this really need to be specified if Default SMTP server is selected?

Mura version 6.0.5368

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

When you select "Use Default SMTP Server" Mura will use the default mail server settings configured in the server (Railo or ColdFusion). Maybe these settings changed